# Oracle out parameter not being NULL'd

Tags: oracle, plsql

My understanding is OUT formal parameters should always be defaulted to NULL when the procedure is called.

```
create or replace package parameter_tests as 
    procedure callerproc;
end parameter_tests;
/
create or replace package body parameter_tests as

procedure getstring(p_str out varchar) is
begin
  if p_str is null then
    dbms_output.put_line('parameter null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('parameter NOT null');
  end if;
  p_str :='zz';
end getstring;


procedure getcursor(p_out out sys_refcursor) is
begin
  if p_out%isopen then
      dbms_output.put_line('cursor open');
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('cursor closed');
  end if;

  open p_out for
    select *
    from dual;
end getcursor;

procedure callerproc is
  lv_cursor sys_refcursor;
  lv_string varchar2(2) := null;
begin
  for i in 1..2 loop
    getstring(lv_string);

    getcursor(lv_cursor);
  end loop;

end callerproc;
end parameter_tests;
/

set serveroutput on
begin
  parameter_tests.CALLERPROC;
end;
/
```

parameter_tests.getstring would expect to output "Parameter null" both times around the callerproc loop.  And when you run the code that's exactly what happens.

However the output from parameter_tests.getcursor indicates the reference cursor is still open the second time around the loop.

If the formal parameter p_out was being nulled when getcursor was called, we'd expect it to close the reference cursor. Instead it passes the open reference cursor and it's actually the OPEN FOR that tidies up the open reference cursor (and prevents us from hitting the maximum open cursors if you loop hundreds of times).

If I manually null the reference cursor between calls it does behave like we would expect.

Can anyone tell me why reference cursors are being handled as a special case when they are OUT parameters? And also what other types are handled differently?

The database version is 11.2.0.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS572):

> When declaring a cursor variable as the formal parameter of a subprogram:
>
> - If the subprogram opens or assigns a value to the cursor variable, then the parameter mode must be IN OUT.
> - If the subprogram only fetches from, or closes, the cursor variable, then the parameter mode can be either IN or IN OUT.

The cursor parameter seems to be treated as if it had been declared as IN OUT, even though you only actually declare it as OUT. The behaviour is what you would expect to see from IN OUT; you can even fetch the cursor in the second call, and see the dummy value from dual.

It sort of makes sense given the nature of the ref cursor as a pointer, but you would think that rule would be enforced by the compiler erroring if only OUT was specified (and it isn't even reported as a warning). The example in the docs works fine with just OUT too, incidentally.

So really this looks like a compiler bug since it doesn't report the incorrect parameter direction; but also (more tenuously!) a bug in your code because it isn't declared as IN OUT. And, possibly, a further bug because you don't explicitly close the cursor - which does appear to 'fix' the issue too, sort of:

```
procedure callerproc is
  lv_cursor sys_refcursor;
  lv_string varchar2(20) := null;
begin
  for i in 1..2 loop
    getstring(lv_string);

    getcursor(lv_cursor);
    
    close lv_cursor;
  end loop;

end callerproc;
```

which is probably more correct than assigning null to the cursor variable, which you mentioned also works.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. You are right about explicit closing being the best choice. The source of the question was actually investigating a problem with unclosed cursors and we discovered we couldn't exceed the cursor limit by opening them in a loop.